# Illustrator Blend Tool even size differences?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending-objects

In Illustrator I am creating a spiral with hands drawing hands drawing hands drawing hands drawing....

[image]

The way I am doing this is; I make a BIG and a very small copy of the 'hand' and then I use the 'blend tool' which I set to 'specified steps' and use around 30-50 steps. It would be important that the size difference between the steps should be proportional.

[image]

I made measurements and at the end, the small 'hands' are getting smaller in a much bigger rate.
I thought the point of the 'blend tool' (in this case, where both ends are the same exact objects, but different in size) is to make a proportional chain of the objects with equal changes at every single step.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to achieve what I would like; to get ~50 smaller objects so every single step is proportional to the previous one?

(sorry if my english isn't perfect and I hope it is clear, what I am looking for)

Comment: Why not use transform each?

Answer (score 1):

Blends in Illustrator are *not* really about precision. They are about iterations. Blend object sizes and spacing are entirely dependent upon the length of segments between anchors. Shorter path segments result in tighter spacing.

While on a single path with only end anchors things appear fine, when you start introducing more anchors and varied path segment lengths things change. You can see this by just adding a third anchor point to your single path segment.

As your curve reduces, the segments between anchor points get shorter and shorter. This necessitates the object getting smaller and smaller so they fit (100%) within the space allotted. A blend won't "cut off" or "truncate" the object being blended at anchors, or overlap objects on top of anchors. All objects for that segment *must* fit between the segment anchors. So, if 5.8 objects fit, Illustrator reduces the objects, or tightens spacing, so 6 of them fit (I don't know the exact math, numbers are just an example). There is *some* rounding which occurs, but again, I can't explain the *exact* rounding math.

If you want precision, you probably need to expand the blend and *manually* alter size or position of the smaller objects. Or, possibly *cut* the path and create multiple blend paths that allow you more control over the `Specified Steps` for each section. This would allow you to kind of control, in a loose manner, the size of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to adjust the Big and small graphic scale and the steps relationship?

Say your big graphic is 100% and you make your small graphic 10% of the big graphics. Next you make the blend in 8 steps, will the blend steps have better proportion?

Another method will be create different key graphics along the path.

Instead of two key graphics
(100%)-----(10%)

You create five key graphics
(100%)-(75%)-(50%)-(25%)-(10%)

Just make sure the graphics are in correct front-end order.